# How to activate a tab that has a validation error in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am building a tabbed angular form where each tab has different sections of the form that need to be filled out (similar to Magento and the product setup page).

I want to validate the form, and then focus attention to the first tab that had a validation error (and perhaps highlight that tab).

I am using `ui-router-extra` for the *sticky* states so that each tab is a separate child route... however I believe this might not be relevant as the routes are simply hidden, not removed from the DOM.

What methodologies should I  be using to achieve such functionality?

Validation is going to be done through Angular as well as server side.

1 way is to have an object that has a list of all fields and the tab that they are contained in. When I get a validation error, I could look this field up and then do a `$state.go` to show that tab to the user. However, I am looking for a more dynamic way.

Comment: What's preventing you from validating each tab before moving to next? Seems like it would be easier to code and more user friendly. If it's all one form tag you can still use nested `ng-form` but since you are using routes for tabs I doubt it is all one `<form>` anyway

Comment: Mmmm, I hope you should set up a handler for error, for example onFieldError (At scope) then set a global variable with the error data (the section that came from, the type or whatever you need) then just redirect route to that section making a routing table...